# Error running apt-get update in python 2.7

Tags: python

I set up a new environment with `python 2.7` and when I run:
`sudo apt-get update`
I get the following error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`
I cannot switch to a newer version of python because I am trying to install kaldi which depends on python 2.7.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Has anyone solved this before?
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try running this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-apt
```

If this not work, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i) post(It is for python 3 but by tweaking a few thing it should work for 2 as well)